# Word for a non-professional job done as a hobby

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a programmer, but not professionally. I do have [apps](http://creativecactusapps.weebly.com) on the Google Play Store, but it's mainly a hobby (and I don't earn much at all; about a few cents a month).

I'm sure there must be a word for this type of job (i.e. a non-professional job done mainly as a hobby), but I don't know what it is.

Comment: How about **Dabbler**? One who takes part in an activity casually.

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan Possibly, but it doesn't suggest that they partly do it as a non-professional pursuit.

Comment: Are you looking for *avocation*?

Comment: `Hobby Programmer` is a long-established word

Comment: I think you mean Hobbyist.  A hobby programmer would program hobbies.    Which, if you're creating games, I suppose you are.

Comment: You want to describe the **hobby** or the **hobbyist**?

Comment: @CandleOrange --  You are right. Hobbyist Programmer is the more suitable  word and more common too. I do remember running into "Hobby Programmer" quite a few times in the shareware era though, and it stuck with me.

Comment: @deadrat That's not a bad suggestion. Maybe you could add it as an answer?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to simply call it a hobby?

Comment: Any more, if you're a non-professional programmer you're *hobbled*.

Answer (score 10):

I think [**hobby**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hobby) itself would do just fine. [**Hobbyists**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hobbyist) work at their [craft](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/craft) when it’s *fun and convenient*, but don’t make the necessary commitment needed to get to the [professional](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/professional) level.

*"Selling apps on Play Store is my **hobby**"*.

So you may be a **"hobbyist programmer "**. Some people actually [hate that name.](http://www.itworld.com/article/2702038/application-management/hobbyist-programmers--don-t-call-us-hobbyists.html)

> a hobbyist programmer is somebody who spends 10 or more hours a month programming, but is not paid primarily to be a programmer.

---

What you're describing may also be a [**sideline**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sideline) career.

> An activity done in addition to one’s main job, especially to earn extra income
>
> [As modifier]: a sideline career as a stand-up comic

*"He founded the fast-food company as a **sideline** to his petrol station"*

Comment: This is the closest answer so far, and I like the link to the article - very interesting. Though I think it is a bit stuck-up to be offended by such a neutral term as "hobbyist programmer"! It's what I call myself.

Comment: @DogLover I'm actually a hobbyist photographer/musician, myself. My professional skills are in civil engineering and project management.

Comment: Oh, really? I'm a hobbyist photographer too, albeit to a much lesser extent.

Comment: I like your answer but with one remark: "don't make the necessary commitment needed to get to the professional level". That is often, but not always true. There are people who can do professional grade things as a hobby. Just one example: Friend of mine, as a hobby, restores leaded-glass windows. He is considered an expert in that field, but because there isn't enough work to make a living in that business his day-job is being a safety-inspector/advisor working in the oil industry.

Answer (score 5):

You might consider [*avocation*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20avocation&oq=define%20avocation&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.13732j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which means a hobby, from the Latin *a(b)* (away) + *vocare* (to call), i.e, something that calls one away from the profession or occupation at which one makes a living.  There is no implication that you necessarily are a beginner or are unaccomplished at your avocation, just that it's a sideline.

Comment: The nice thing about avocation is that it evokes contrast to vocation, so "it's not my day job" is obvious.

Comment: This seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for ***[amateur](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/amateur)***:

> - One who engages in an art, science, study, or athletic activity as a pastime rather than as a profession.

(AHD)

or:

- you should probably define yourself a ***"programmer"***, the fact that you do it professionally or not is not related to the competence you have developed.

Comment: +1 I see what you're getting at, but if you use it in the phrase *amateur programmer* it sounds like you're saying that you are a beginner/mediocre programmer.

Comment: @DogLover - Probably "dilettante" is closer to the definition of "beginner/mediocre non-professional." The alternative is "non-professional programmer".

Comment: +1 I like to tinker with code at times, and I know the ABCs. I wouldn't call myself a programmer, but, amateur definitely works in *my* case.

Comment: This is one of those things where the original meaning of a word would be perfect, but that meaning is so overshadowed by later understandings (initially misunderstandings!) that it’s difficult to use in its original sense without explaining. The only place you tend to still see *amateur* used in its original sense is in the names of sports leagues where *professionals* are not allowed (e.g. an Amateur Cup would not allow a pro to compete, to keep things fair for the amateurs who also have to maintain a day job).

Answer (score 3):

You might consider, [***pastime***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278632/what-is-your-preferred-pastime-programming-project)

> An activity that occupies one's spare time pleasantly: *Sailing is her favorite pastime.*
>
> [Middle English passe tyme, translation of French passe temps : passer, to pass + temps, time.]
>
> [The American Heritage® Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Pastime&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)

Comment: This is just a synonym for hobby.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly dated expression, but one I still use is ***a labour of love***.

Comment: @NVZ Yes I think you will be understood.

Answer (score 0):

An “amateur”

An amateur is when you enjoy doing something (and are particularly good at it) as a hobby (for fun not money) instead of doing it professionally (get paid to do it).

Comment: This is just a rephrasing of an [existing answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/315298/80039).

Answer (score -2):

***Dilettante*** fits the bill nicely:

> a ​person who is or ​seems to be ​interested in a ​subject, but whose ​understanding of it is not very ​deep or ​serious ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dilettante))

...especially if you are emphasising the non-professional aspect.

Comment: I don't think it does fit nicely as I **do** have considerable knowledge of programming. I meant non-professional as in I am not employed, etc.

Comment: @DogLover **"If you're really good at something, never do it for free."** - The Joker

Answer (score -2):

If you're not **amateur** level (which would be correct world, implying that you do something just for the love of it, but also has a negative tone), you may use

**craftsman** - someone who is skilled at a craft, but doesn't necessarily has to have it as a (current) job.

-> [Software Craftsmanship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_craftsmanship)

Answer (score -2):

Enthusiast - a person who is very interested in a particular activity or subject.

Comment: I presume you mean 'enthusiasm' as the question asks about the activity not the person.

Comment: Hi jim, your answer has been flagged as low-quality, possibly because it's too short or not detailed enough. As @Chenmunka pointed out, the question was asking for a word describing the activity, not the person. Also, I would recommend that you include a dictionary definition of enthusiasm to support your assertion that it fits OP's needs. - [From Review](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/171558)

Comment: @Chenmunka OP asks for what the 'job' is called, not an activity. "Programming enthusiast" is a good suggestion for this request.