# Expression for someone who is not a professional, but still an expert

Tags: single-word-requests

In our day and age you don't need to go to university or college to become an expert at something: encyclopedias, instant access to tens of thousands of textbooks and classics (both free and not), papers, discussion boards, educational videos and actual filmed lectures at the most prestigious of universities, Q&A sites where it's not rare for an answerer to have a PhD, the following question seems very topical (to me, at least).

**What expression is best suitable for a person who does not hold a degree in something, but is still an expert in this something (sometimes ironically being a better expert than one who does hold a degree)?**

The best expression that comes to mind is 'enthusiast', but it's not serious enough, in my opinion.

Comment: What's wrong with your suggestion of **expert**?

Comment: This doesn't full answer your question, but may be interesting: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/315297/184766

Comment: It seems to imply you've had some formal training of sorts to become one.

Comment: perhaps, but do bear in mind that lots of people - including EL&U contributers - would call themselves *experts* without having had official training in that topic.

Comment: An expert is an expert. If you want to emphasize the lack of formal training, you could add *self-taught* or *autodidact*.

Comment: Unfortunately there are lots of people who are [“qualified but not certified”](http://inalj.com/?p=23988) who aren’t permitted to practice their professions, but what’s really scary is the number who are permitted to practice even though they’re “certified but not qualified” to do so.

Comment: @michael.hor257k you're absolutely right - an expert is an expert is an expert. Everything is fine when you look up the word in a dictionary, but things become different when you actually talk to people. It is this connotation of having had formal training, pragmatic inference that is made by the listener that adds to the meaning of what the word means objectively. _This_ is ultimately what I want to avoid by asking my question.

Comment: I don't think there is any particular connotation of formal training associated with the word *expert*, even if many experts have had formal training/education related to their areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enlightened people care about expertise in a particular area X, not about credentials, e.g. advanced degrees, professional certifications. The latter are meaningless compared to what a person knows or can do.

That said, the word you are looking for may be *authority*.

From Merriam-Webster:

> *authority*: an individual cited or appealed to as an expert

An *authority* is a person who simply knows more about a particular something than anyone else, or most anyone else. Whether such a person has a degree or not simply shouldn't matter.

Comment: I couldn't have come up with a better word. +1.

Comment: @alwayslearning Greetings. That's a high compliment coming from you. Thanks!